# How to show a loading image in KendoUI Autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

I have following code for Autocomplete.

```
$("#input").kendoAutoComplete({
        minLength: 4,
        dataTextField: "ProductName",
        template: kendo.template($('#productAutoCompleteTemplate').html()),
        dataSource: {
            serverFiltering: true,
            data: "json",
            transport: {
                read: {
                    url: productSearchUrl,
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: "post"
                },
                parameterMap: function(data) {
                    return {
                        searchText: $('input.txtProductText', $panelBar.select()).val()
                    };
                }
            }

        },
        select: onProductSelected
    });
```

Autocomplete working fine. But I need to show a loading image until the data has been retrieved from the server. How can I implement this with KendoUI Autocomplete?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily with the help of the dataSource [events **requestStart** and **requestEnd**](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#events-requestStart). Respectively you can show() and hide() your loading gif or whatever your loading animation is.